# Stop form submission if textfield is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to stop a form submission when textfield is empty. But with my current script even when the textfield is empty and you should and check the database you can see a newly inserted empty records

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#form1").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

if ($("#username").val() != '') {
    }
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: "username.php",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {
        $("input[type=text]").val("");


        });
    });
});
```

Comment: have you no form validation on the form?

Comment: i do. i use the jquery validation plugin

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api android support has partial support for the required field as far back as 4.2 the current version is 5.1 I reckon its your best bet!!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. HTML5 provides built-in attributes for form element validations
2. You can use **required** attribute with your input tag

Refer link [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) for example and details

Comment: the final product will be tested on phones and some android browsers don't support the html 5 required attribute

Answer (score 1):

I think it's only a logical problem, the parenthesis before the AJAX call is the one the `if` statement is referring, so the `if` block results empty and the AJAX call is executed every time.

Answer (score 0):

Before submit you can check form is valid or not using below code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var form = $("#formid");
     var validationError = $(form).valid();
     if (validationError) {
      // form submit
     }
 });
```